# Import Underscore to Angular 2 CLI project

Tags: javascript, angular, systemjs, angular-cli

I've started a new project with the Angular CLI tool. After that I follow [this official guide](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/3rd-party-libs#adding-underscore-library-to-your-project) to import Underscore and I do *exactly* as it says.

But still my project crashes in the browser when I try to use Underscore in my app.component with the error message:

> ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: ReferenceError: _ is not defined

Underscore is added to the dist/vendor folder so my guess would be that the problem is in the Systemjs configuration.

Here is my angular-cli-build:

```
var Angular2App = require('angular-cli/lib/broccoli/angular2-app');

module.exports = function(defaults) {
  return new Angular2App(defaults, {
    sassCompiler: {
      includePaths: [
        'src/styles'
      ]
    },
    vendorNpmFiles: [
      'systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js',
      'systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
      'zone.js/dist/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
      'es6-shim/es6-shim.js',
      'reflect-metadata/**/*.+(ts|js|js.map)',
      'rxjs/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
      'underscore/underscore.js',
      '@angular/**/*.+(js|js.map)'
    ]
  });
};
```

Here is my system-config:

```
"use strict";

// SystemJS configuration file, see links for more information
// https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs
// https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/config-api.md

/***********************************************************************************************
 * User Configuration.
 **********************************************************************************************/
/** Map relative paths to URLs. */
const map: any = {
  'underscore':                 'vendor/underscore/',
};

/** User packages configuration. */
const packages: any = {
  'underscore':                 { main: 'underscore.js', format: 'cjs' },
};

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/***********************************************************************************************
 * Everything underneath this line is managed by the CLI.
 **********************************************************************************************/
const barrels: string[] = [
  // Angular specific barrels.
  '@angular/core',
  '@angular/common',
  '@angular/compiler',
  '@angular/forms',
  '@angular/http',
  '@angular/router',
  '@angular/platform-browser',
  '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',

  // Thirdparty barrels.
  'rxjs',

  // App specific barrels.
  'app',
  'app/shared',
  /** @cli-barrel */
];

const cliSystemConfigPackages: any = {};
barrels.forEach((barrelName: string) => {
  cliSystemConfigPackages[barrelName] = { main: 'index' };
});

/** Type declaration for ambient System. */
declare var System: any;

// Apply the CLI SystemJS configuration.
System.config({
  map: {
    '@angular': 'vendor/@angular',
    'rxjs': 'vendor/rxjs',
    'main': 'main.js'
  },
  packages: cliSystemConfigPackages
});

// Apply the user's configuration.
System.config({ map, packages });
```

My app.component:

```
/// <reference path="../../typings/globals/underscore/index.d.ts" />

import { Component } from '@angular/core';

declare var _;

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `<h1>{{title}}</h1>`
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = _.version;
}
```

Where do I go wrong?

And *WHY* is this so complicated? Will the community accept it being this cumbersome to just add a simple third party library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your configuration basically sets up `underscore` so SystemJS can find it when needed.

When you changed **`system-config.ts`**, you told SystemJS: if anyone asks for `underscore`, it is a file `underscore.js` that can be found at the `vendor/underscore/` folder -- and its module format is CommonJS (`cjs`).

The changes at **`angular-cli-build.js`** are for telling angular-cli what files it should pick and throw into the `vendor` folder. (So, if you told SystemJS it'd find underscore there, this is what makes it be there.)

But that alone **does not import/add** underscore into the global scope of your app.

You have to import it at each `.ts` file so SystemJS adds it to the transpiled `.js` of that module.

Instead of these two lines:

```
/// <reference path="../../typings/globals/underscore/index.d.ts" />
declare var _;
```

Add this to your file:

```
import * as _ from 'underscore';
```

---

If you have problems, try to inspect the generated .js source being executed at the browser. In your case, you'll probably find that there is no `require()` method importing the `underscore`.

Comment: I've tried this already and it doesn't work. How should the system.js settings look like to make this work?

Comment: I don't really know underscore, it really depends on each lib, but your code seems it could be correct (I'm saying could because I don't know exactly). What version of underscore are you using? Are you importing it as dev or production dependency?

Comment: I use version 1.8.3 and have added it to the regular dependencies.
The library is added to my dist/vendor folder, so I guess that angular-cli-build is correct, and that the problem is the systemjs config.

Comment: OK, I'll have a look at the underscore source. Gimme a minute.

Comment: What typings are you using? `dt~underscore` does not have `_.version` at it, yielding a compile error.

Comment: Look, I created a project, exactly like yours, added `import * as _ from 'underscore';` and it works...

Comment: I created a project containing a new project and the changes needed to add underscore. Check the commit: https://github.com/acdcjunior/EXXAMPLE/commit/6a0db9bc10d11c331dfb305e2c28e5de7d965da2 This is the diff needed to add underscore.

Comment: Huh, so in the end it was just the typings that didn't contain the .version... Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The doco adding 3rd party lib is misleading.
I have been banging my head for over an hour!

```
declare var _; // this won't work.
```

What you need is

```
/// <reference path="../../../typings/globals/underscore/index.d.ts" />
import * as _ from 'underscore';
```